# Understanding CSS for positioning <p> & <h1>

Tags: html, css

i have some css code which should arrange html tags like this:*(an edited image, showing how i want to arrange elements with css)*
[image]

Here is the code for my css styling:

```
.hbox
{   margin-top:15px;
width:100%;     
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.3), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.3), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.3), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.hbox p{
margin-top:-8%;
margin-left:25px;
padding-bottom:6px;
font-size:12px;
color:#859489;
text-shadow:#6F7678 0px 0px 1px;
}
.hbox h3{
position:relative;
top:0px;
margin-left:3px;
font-size:45px;
color:#78A4AD;
text-shadow:#6F7678 0px 1px 2px;
}
```

So, i have put this on my html page

```
<div class="hbox">
<h3>1</h3><p>This is a demo postr<br>lorem ipsum spsum</p>
</div>
<div class="hbox">
<h3>2</h3><p>This is a demo postr</p>
</div>
```

The output of this css is frustrating :
[image]

How to arrange it perfectly. Is that i have made it complex. Sorry for the dumb question... i'm just learning css...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make adjustments to the values to fit your needs but please view the Fiddle I created here: http://jsfiddle.net/EezLZ/

There's actually a few important adjustments I made to your CSS to use more relative value to make all the positioning easier.  I added quite a few comments in the CSS portion of the fiddle, please also check those out, but there's some explanation on the major changes...

```
.hbox {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:2em;
  padding:0.15em;
  padding-left:3em;
  /* ... */
}
```

**position:relative**

Since `hbox` is your primary container, give it `position:relative` so all child elements can be positioned based on it's containment.  Without this, at least some browsers could use parent container elements.  We will want to position big number in relation to it's parent, so this is necessary.

**margin-top:2em**

Since we want the number to overlap part of the top and we want spacing between the boxes, give each box a 2em distance.  1em will cover some spacing between boxes and 1em to help account for a partial overlap of the number.  Of course, you can adjust the value as desired for your design.  Also note, working in EM's will help make this design easier to adjust (instead of pixels).

**padding:0.15em**

Give the box some standard padding all the way around the box.  Again, this value can be easily adjust as desired for your design.

**padding-left:3em**

Our desire is to have a large "number" on the left.  We're going to "hover" this number which will remove it from the "flow" of the document.  So, we will need to reserve some space in the box to account for this.  Otherwise, the content in the box will flow under the number and the number will overlap it.

```
.hbox h3 {
  position:absolute;
  top:-0.5em;
  left:0.1em;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size:300%;
}
```

**position:absolute;**

Our setup of the `hbox` styles leads to this.  Absolutely position your "number" element to remove it from flow and allow you to place it anywhere in relation to it's container.

**top:-0.5em;**

`top:0` would place the element flush with the top of the box.  We want a little overhand so we move it up a little more by using a negative value.  A positive value would move the element down, away from the top.  Again, adjust the actual value per your design needs.

**left:0.1em;**

Just like top, `left:0` would place the element flush to the left edge of the container.  I just gave it a little spacing.  Adjust as desired.

**margin:0; padding:0;**

Browsers can give default padding/margin to elements.  Set these to zero so they don't interfere with the design.

**font-size:300%;**

Use percentages (or EMs) for your font size (vs pixels).  This can help keep cleaner design and adjust your elements more accurately.  Now you know that this number is "3 times larger" than the base font.  If the base font is 1em, three times larger is 3em.  This helps you adjust padding/margin without having to guess pixel sizes. And if your base font size changes, everything should scale relatively.

```
.hbox p {
  font-size:75%;
  color:#859489;
  text-shadow:#6F7678 0px 0px 1px;
}
```

Note, you don't need to try and position your content because you setup your container and title to do it.  You just need to style it as desired.

**Weakness**

Note item of note... the weakness of this design can be the absolutely positioned number.  Because it's removed from the workflow, the container box with little to no content could cause the number to also overlap the bottom edge, for sufficiently large numbers (ie. if you increase the font-size of the  tag large enough and you have a single line, with very little padding).

This weakness should be minor because you would have to have a fairly large font-size and sufficiently small content for this to happen, but it could be an edge case.

I hope that helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle that demonstrates how this new design helps make the style adjust to all kinds of changes. http://jsfiddle.net/EezLZ/2/

Comment: Nice answer. In terms of the weaknesses, here's a solution that doesn't use absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/QNz9r/

Comment: @Alohci Nice change but it has a weakness of inline-ing all the elements.  Short paragraphs will end up on the same line.  I also generally accept `inline-block` for design but with the note IE7 doesn't have native support. See how it breaks in box 6 acts.  That might not be a desired effect. http://jsfiddle.net/QNz9r/1/

Comment: Yes, you are right about short paragraphs ending up on the same line. It's easy to adapt the solution though by adding a div to wrap the paragraphs. The div becomes the inline-block element, and the paragraphs, lists etc inside it remain display:block. Never ideal to have to change the markup, but CSS still has some weakness. Anyway, see variant 7 at http://jsfiddle.net/QNz9r/2/

Comment: There you go.  Nice adjustment!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting `text-align:center;` in

```
 .hbox p{
margin-top:-8%;
margin-left:25px;
padding-bottom:6px;
font-size:12px;
color:#859489;
text-shadow:#6F7678 0px 0px 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about like this: [jsfiddle.net/xGyN8/](http://jsfiddle.net/xGyN8/)
I just adding

```
.hbox h3{
    display:inline;
    top:-20px;
 }
.hbox p{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-10%;  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can specify **width** and **height** to **.hbox** this will work:

```
.hbox
{   
    margin-top:15px;
    width:300px;
    height: 70px;    
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.3), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.3), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.3), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    position:relative; 
}
.hbox p{
    top:-8%;
    left:55px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#859489;
    text-shadow:#6F7678 0px 0px 1px;
    position:absolute;
}

.hbox h3{
    font-size:45px;
    color:#78A4AD;
    text-shadow:#6F7678 0px 1px 2px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:-60px;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39j8n/